# Can I use AWS Amplify to create SQS that triggers lambda function when a new image is uploaded into S3

Tags: aws-amplify

I know how to use AWS Amplify to create a lambda function that is triggered when a new image is uploaded into S3 but what I want is to use AWS Amplify to create SQS that will trigger a lambda function when a new image is uploaded into S3.

Is this doable using AWS Amplify.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could someone from AWS Amplify team answer this question please.

Comment: You can add S3 trigger to invoke lambda whenever image is uploaded using amplify

Answer (score 1):

I added SQS to my AWS Amplify following the steps in https://medium.com/@navvabian/how-to-add-an-sqs-queue-to-your-amplify-cli-bootstrapped-project-cb7781c636ed